# How to make a heading with image and text horizontally center?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I have an image and a text. I need the text should follow after the image in a row.
And after alignment of both side by side like [image]Time tracker , make both content horizontally center of the screen as a heading of the current page.
What i tried to do is given below.

```
 <div class="row">
      <div class="col-80 col-offset-10">

          <div class="appheadingcenter">

            <img src="img/clock.png" alt="clock" class="clockwidth"></img>
            <div class="timesheettext2">
              <h1 class="timesheettext">
                <b>Timesheet Tracking</b>
              </h1>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: i suggest u to create a jsfiddle or sth similar, there u can play easily with css to achieve those things which u want..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give following css. `display:flex` will make image and text side by side and `justify-content: center;` will make it horizontally center.

```
.appheadingcenter {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. Your answer is currently flagged "low quality" and might eventually be removed.

Comment: i would like to know more about flex concept.
what should i have to do a particular div vertically center in flex concept?

Comment: @Visprasad `align-items: center;` will do it. more details https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex and  play with it here.https://jsfiddle.net/k5d8qnb0/

Comment: its on the top, not vertically centre. i have to make it centre of the screen.

Comment: @Visprasad Ohh then use `.row {
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}`  https://jsfiddle.net/k5d8qnb0/3/

Answer (score 2):

here is a technique using `display: flex;`

Note: click full page to see the bigger picture of this demo

```css
 .header-frame {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        position: absolute;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 }

 .image-frame {
  display: inline-block;
  background: url("https://bobagaming.files.wordpress.com/2015/10/league-of-legends-world-championship-logo-eps-vector-image.png") no-repeat center;
  width: calc(4vw + 4vh);
  height: calc(4vw + 4vh);
  background-size: cover;
 }

 .text-frame {
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-size: calc(2.5vw + 2.5vh);
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1vh 1vw;
 }
```

```html
<div class="header-frame">
 <span class="image-frame"></span>
 <h3 class="text-frame">World Championships</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: make it exact centre of the screen

Comment: check it out now. i centered it exactly on the screen (x = 50, y = 50), is this right ? or you want it centered on top (x = 50, y = 0) ?

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div class="appheadingcenter" style="margin:auto;width:454px;">

                <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/33/Vanamo_Logo.png" 
        alt="clock" class="clockwidth" style="float: left;max-width: 100px;max-height: 100px;">
                <div class="timesheettext2" style="width: 341px;float: left;">
                  <h1 class="timesheettext">
                    <b>Timesheet Tracking</b>
                  </h1>
                </div>
    </div>
```

**Updated Answer**

If you don't want to fix width then use below solution

```html
<div class="appheadingcenter" style="text-align:center;">

      <div style="display: inline-block;">
                <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/33/Vanamo_Logo.png" 
        alt="clock" class="clockwidth" style="float: left;max-width: 100px;max-height: 100px;">
                <div class="timesheettext2" style="width: 341px;float: left;">
                  <h1 class="timesheettext">
                    <b>Timesheet Tracking</b>
                  </h1>
                </div>
              </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: i don,t think setting width like 454 px , is a good idea to follow, i don't think it will give exact center in every device.

Comment: what is the logic behind this? how come you are able to confirm its absolutely center?

Comment: In my solution, the style `text-align:center;` is responsible to put all content in center. but it won't work with normal div so i have added `display: inline-block;` in its child div to apply the center style on that. And i have also apply `float:left;` style on both image and text so that both comes in same line.